# How to search through all items of a combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, search, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a combobox, and I would like to search through every element in it.

How can I do this? (also the number of items is not the same everytime, but this is not so important).

I am using c# windows form application.

Comment: There already are a lot of questions including answers on stackoverflow, for searching trough all items in a combobox...

Comment: Soner Gonul: it's a simple combobox, with 2 items in it. what is to show, really?! it was added visually in c# windows forms...

Comment: There are API methods to do exactly that: [FindString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstring.aspx), [FindStringExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact.aspx)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < myComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
     string value = myComboBox.GetItemText(myComboBox.Items[i]); 
}
```

Comment: could you help a bit more please? this code doesn't return correct value.. it returns in the textbox "System.datarow":   string pac = (string)comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = pac;

Comment: you can read like this string pac =comboBox1.Text;

Comment: but i want to search for a string match through all the elements in the combobox (inside the "for" loop from your first answer)

Comment: oh man, again THANK YOU A LOT for helping me!! i tried in many ways, but didn't knew this had to be done. have a great day! :)

Comment: `GetItemText` not there any more, use `getContent()`

Answer (score 10):

Use a `foreach` loop. It will iterate all your items of ComboBox regardless of their count, e.g.

```
foreach(var item in myComboBox.Items)
{
// do something with your item
}
```